# How to migrate partial data to another database

Tags: mysql, database, partial, data-migration

This is my first time facing this problem and I'm not really sure how to pursue it.

We've got a site with information on a couple hundred doctors and I need to move all the 'doctors' from one mySQL database to another.  It's a Drupal site and the information is split up among maybe 20 different tables.  The new database is also a Drupal site with the same table structure, but also has new information that can't be lost.

How should I go about getting specific rows from specific tables over to the new database?

And to make it a little harder, all the row ids are auto-incremented.  I'll need to insert them with whatever index id comes next and then update that id in the other related tables. What has to happen in order to get this done?

Comment: `mysqldump` has a "where" option that will do the first part for you. Not sure whether there's an automated tool for the second part, but that sounds like you maybe should do things differently architecture-wise (I don't know how though, as I don't know much about Drupal)

Comment: Hm. At the moment I'm thinking I'll probably end up cloning the database, removing unrelated tables & data, and then doing some sql work to rename all the ids to numbers that won't create conflicts when I insert them in the new database.  Anyone have a better approach?